# Difference between find_asset and file exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

which is the correct way to determine If the asset exists.

**find_asset** or **if File.exist?**

I read find_asset is not the best way to do that.

would like to get good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `File.exist` you need to give the whole path, thats hardcode it. If your file is in assets folder, using `find_asset` is easier I guess.